# How to use resolve MISRA C error for assembly language inline function?

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I am using compiler related assembly language function asm() in my PIC32 MCU C code.  My code is compiled and working fine with just using asm("reset") function in my C code.When checking MISRA compliance I am getting following MISRA error:

> function 'asm' undeclared, assumed to return int [MISRA 2012 Rule 17.3, mandatory]asm("reset");

```
asm("reset");
```

How can I resolve this MISRA error for this assembly language function?  I also tried creating function macro to use it but still getting an error.

> function 'asm' undeclared, assumed to return int [MISRA 2012 Rule 17.3, mandatory]ASM_RESET(void);

```
#define ASM_RESET(void) asm("reset")
ASM_RESET(void);
```

Comment: https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=485 The `#define ASM_RESET(void)` is strange, it is a function macro which takes one argument, should be probably moved into a header file.

Comment: I just need reset option so I hard coded into defined macro. @Kmil

Comment: which checking tool are you using?

Comment: PC-Lint utility @AShellye

Comment: I tried  [solution given here](https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=485)I created new asssm.h file where I defined #define ASM()  asm("reset") and I included that file in test.c file  where I am using this macro still same error. @Kamil

Comment: `asm` is not a function; it is a compiler extension keyword, not standard C so the tool does not recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PC-Lint isn't recognizing `asm` as a keyword.  It is treating it as a function which has no prototype.
You could try adding `+rw(asm)` to the options.

On the other hand, [this forum post](https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=485) suggests that the legal way is to define a `reset` function in standalone file that includes only assembly, and show the C file a prototype for it.

reset.c:

```
void reset(void) {
   asm("reset");
}
```

test.c:

```
#include "reset.h"

...
reset();
```

Comment: I don't think moving the directive to a different file would make it unrecognized.  Did it compile before you moved it? (assuming you ignore the misra error)

Comment: Using this way MISRA error is resolved but by this way code is not compiled.It generate compiler Error: unrecognized opcode `reset '@Ashelly

Comment: Yes it compiles if I directly use asm("reset") in my code.@Ashelly

Comment: If the same command works in one file but not the other, I'd suspect your makefile or build settings.

Comment: I am not creating any makefile by myself .I am using MPLAB X IDE so It will compile and build my code.@Ashelly

Comment: This is the correct approach. Move all assembler code to a separate file, so that it is encapsulated. It can be done through wrapper functions or macros. This separate file should not be checked for MISRA-C compliance, as it should only contain inline assembler. And obviously doesn't fulfil the MISRA rule that all code should conform to ISO C, so you need to make a permanent deviation for that.

Answer (score 0):

`asm` is a compiler extension *keyword*, not a function.  Being compiler specific, it is not automatically recognised by your static analysis tool,and your compiler's inline assembly syntax is "function-like", so it applies the function prototyping rule.

You need to configure PC-Lint correctly using a configuration file or command line options that describe the implementation defined behaviour of your compiler.  That may include a great many options, but in this case you should use:

```
-dasm()=
```

which will cause the analyser to ignore inline assembly code with the function-like syntax `asm(...)`

Alternatively you can ignore the inline assembler syntax during static analysis by conditionally defining a macro that hides all such directives:

```
#if defined _lint
    #define asm( asmstr )
#endif
```

This however would hide other deviations from the checker, such as rules about encapsulation and isolation of in-line assembly.  For that reason you should not use a macro or inline assembly mixed with C code lines, but rather define a wrapper function:

```
void reset(void) 
{
   asm("reset");
}
```

and place the `reset()` function defined above in a separate translation unit and simply omit that source code from the analysis - as if it were library code.

Comment: Is it valid if I write this way __asm("reset") by writing this way neither compiler nor misra showing any error@Clifford

Comment: @raj123 I do not own a copy of the current MISRA C standard, and do not know in any case what version your tool applies nor its coverage, so I cannot tell you.